# What do square brackets mean where used as Promise return Type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, promise

I am a new to typescript world.

I' am actually reviewing some code and I have found this line of code:

```
export function myFunction(user: string): Promise<[ReturnType]>
```

I' m trying to mock the function with a `Promise.resolve` inside my test suite.

I can't find anything about the Type sourraunded with square brackets.

Comment: That's a one-element [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) type, an array of a single element. One-element tuples have limited usefulness, so I'd be a little concerned about something that will return a promise that yields a `[ReturnType]` as opposed to just a `ReturnType`.